# Power Transformer with two Buchholz relays

Tags: transformer, relay, safety, mains, high-voltage

In my workplace we have a power transformer, on its conservator tank there is a device like a Buchholz relay and its named as Atmo-Seal. What is the purpose of this device?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this pdf,](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwibzb7-k9fLAhWEMBoKHdbZAeUQFghOMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cgglobal.com%2Fhu%2Ffiles%2Fbrochures%2FCG_Power_Transformers_ENG_druk_hi.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGoyNb7RFqLUvDi2m6FlboMSKk1rg&bvm=bv.117218890,d.bGs) (see page 16) that would be a relay that signals when the seal that is used to prevent air from getting in contact with the oil is ruptured.

So, you have a Buchholz relay to detect arcing in an oil filled transformer, and then you have the other thing to tell you when the seal around the oil container is bad and you've got air in contact with the oil - which can lead to moisture in the oil and therefore to arcing.

Comment: Well that was a very good document, thank you so much, appreciate it..

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Buchholz switch is to disconnect transformer from mains when activated. It trips when gas is forming inside oil tank, this is due to isolation breakdown in transformer: there is an arc inside, the oil is heating up forming gas, Buchholz detects and turns off.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchholz_relay

Comment: But whats the purpose of atmoseal?